# How to kill suspended processes in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, process, kill

I have found tons of arma3.exe processes in Task Manager on Windows 10. They all have status "Suspended". When I try to kill them, I get the message "Access Denied".

I tried to kill them with `cmd` using `/f /t` but it still shows "Access Denied".

After that I tried `psexec -s` to gain System privileges, but still nothing.

Do you have any idea how to kill those processes?

Comment: Did you try running command prompt as admin and then trying to kill the tasks using those commands?

Comment: It's possible that the process hung in a kernel operation. You have to reboot the OS in order to correctly kill that process.

Comment: So what happens when you resume them? You can do that with Process Explorer.

Comment: From an elevated command prompt **RUN AS ADMINISTRATOR** try **1.** `wmic process where name="arma3.exe" call terminate`. Additionally, if you've not launched the command prompt as administrator with taskkill then try that as well as **2.** `TASKKILL /F /IM "arma3.exe"` and see what result you get. If you still have trouble, checked services.msc and see if it's perhaps running as a service and you're have to complete a **3.** `NET STOP` to kill the executable processes.

Comment: When i'm trying to resume them, it says "Unable to suspend (?!) the process"

Comment: "wmic process where name="arma3.exe" call terminate" Didn't give any result. taskkill fails with "access if denied". In services.msc i didn't see anything somehow connected to arma3.exe.

Comment: Could you tell me how to use NET STOP?

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT - Thank you the wmic process where name="arma3.exe" call terminate worked perfectly for me!!!

Comment: @PreetSangha Wow... I must have missed this from long ago as a comment. I am very happy to hear my advice helped you and I apologize I did not have this as an actual answer. Here are a couple similar answers I've written to help others with similar wmic commands calling terminate.... `1.` https://superuser.com/questions/1100828/add-local-group-restrictions-with-cmd/1101106#1101106 and `2.` https://superuser.com/questions/1002737/how-to-use-wmic-to-kill-a-cmd-exe-instance-searching-by-its-command-line/1005056#1005056 feel free to give one of those an up vote if you like.

Comment: Or do you think maybe I should write an answer with this comment detail I made to keep the content more helpful for the specific problem asked about here which lead you to this post? Any feedback is appreciated!! I wasn't tagged in the original response so I cannot confirm that I ever saw the OP's reply or not from memory.

Answer (score 1):

If you are fine with using a third-party program I would suggest using [Process Hacker](https://processhacker.sourceforge.io) for this. Process Hacker allows you to search for specific processes (arma in your case) and kill it, and the tree.

I can tell you the steps here how to do it:

1. Open Process Hacker
2. [image] Using process hacker, search for the process you would like to kill. In this case, I used Steam as an example.
3. [image] When you have the selected process, right-click and either select Terminate or Terminate tree. If you select terminate, it will terminate the process and nothing else, while terminating the tree would kill any process associated with it as well. **If the process fails to close, Process Hacker will tell you and ask for UAC permission.**

Answer (score 0):

I believe launching command prompt as admin and doing

taskkill /f /im taskname

should do the trick. That's what I've always used and never had any issues with it.
You could also try unsuspending it, though I'm not sure it'll help. Go to resource monitor (at the bottom of the performance panel in task manager) and you can unsuspend from there. If none of that works I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing better than DTaskManager.exe which can replace taskmanager and terminate any process (or group of process) including system , bypassing permissions:
http://dimio.altervista.org/eng/#DTaskManager

Answer (score 0):

Open `Task Manager` (Ctrl+Shift+Esc), go to `Details` tab, right click the application hanging, click `End Process Tree`.

Answer (score -1):

Here’s how I do it.

Open task manager and go to processes so you can see the PID

Find the service that is hung and make note of that PID

OPEN COMMAND PROMPT as admin and type taskkill /f /PID (there is a space between PID and the PID you want to use(PID you wrote down goes here)

That will take care of it usually. Otherwise a reboot is needed.

Comment: The question states that that doesn't work.